# Questions about using "to+ ing"

Tags: ing

I heard this sentence in a film:

> We are one step closer to ending this.

I do not know why we have to use "ending" instead of "end".

Is "Step to" a phrasal verb?

Answer (score 4):

Often, one finds oneself explaining that the word **to** preceding (often, but not necessarily, immediately) a verb form is not the preposition but the infinitive marker:

*I want to go there.*

*Is it all right to eat in here?*

*Try to* / *and keep awake.*

*To see is to believe.*

*To err is human, to forgive, divine.*

*Their mission was to boldly go where no man had been before.*

Notice that the verb form following the *to* is the base form; together with the infinitive marker, this constitutes the 'to-infinitive' form of the verb.

However, the *to* used here is the preposition (or arguably, particle - *close to* can often be replaced by *near* - and *closer to* by *nearer* - making *close to* a multi-word preposition):

*We are closer to Denver than we were.*

*We are three miles closer to home.*

*We are one step closer to a lasting solution.*

*We are one step closer to ending this.*

As Gulliver says, *ending* here is a word with both noun and verb properties, but the *to* is not the same word we use in *I want to end this now*.

Answer (score 3):

Here, *step* means *stage*, and *one step closer* is a set phrase.

Here, the gerund *ending* is used, but you could also say *the end **of** this*. The -ing form is a bit like a noun.

Answer (score 2):

In this case *to* is a preposition, not the first half of an infinitive.  We can say "We are one step closer to the end of this" with the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Here, *to* is a preposition of the adjective *closer*, and after preposition usually gerund is used.